# Handle events between different templates

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, templates, meteor

I have a template A inside template B. When button B inside template B is clicked, the button A in template A should change color.

I'm using Session get/set to change a variable so that I can make the color changed.

Here's my code:

```
 Session.set('monitor',0);


    Template.B.events({ 
         'click #buttonB' :function(event){
              Session.set('monitor',1);
          }
         return FlowRouter.go('/templateC');
    })

/*NOT WORKING */
    Template.A.helpers({
         randomlyNamed: function(){
          if (Session.get('monitor') == 1){
              document.getElementById("buttonA").style.background = "red";

          }
        Session.set('monitor',0);
    } 
    })
```

**The Issue:** The session can be set to 1 when the buttonB's clicked. The problem is that I'm not sure where to put the change-color code inside template A.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can set the style in the helper and refer to it in your template.

html (in Template A):

```
<button id="buttonA" style="background-color: {{btnColor}}">
```

js:

```
Template.A.helpers({
  btnColor(){ return (Session.get('monitor') == 1)? "red" : "black"; }
})
```

here `black` is the alternative color but it can be anything.

Comment: Thanks! This is exactly what I've been looking for. One question, how would you set the monitor back to 0 after the color's changed?

Comment: If you did the color would change back. In this pattern the Session variable directly controls the color. If you want to only change the color when the button is clicked then you should directly set the color in the original template event.